# How to add Relationship of Factories to faker in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, faker

I have models like this:

```
Entity - entities table
Address - address table
User - users table
Geoloc - geoloc table
UserEntity - entity_user table
```

Now Entity can have one address and one geoloc, but it can have multiple users this is what UserEntity is for.

So I need to do a pattern where factory will create it like this:

User>Entity>Address>Geoloc>UserEntity

so when user is created it will also create entity, address and geoloc, associate entity id to address, associate geoloc id to entity and insert user_id and entity_id to user entity.

Here's my current setup:

AddressFactory:

```
$factory->define(App\Address::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'building_name' => $faker->company,
        'address' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'town' => $faker->city,
        'postcode' => $faker->postcode,
        'telephone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'private' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 50),
        'entity_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Entity::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

EntityFactory:

```
factory->define(App\Entity::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->company,
        'type' => 'Service',
        'tags' => 'mens clothes, online shopping, ladies clothes',
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'logo' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480),
        'cover' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 1000, $height = 600),
        'bio' => $faker->catchPhrase,
        'main' => $faker->realText($maxNbChars = 200, $indexSize = 2),
        'twitter_business' => 'OfficialOAFC',
        'facebook_business' => 'MolinoLounge',
        'instagram_business' => 'OfficialOAFC',
        'google_places' => 'ChIJvaCBHYG3e0gRfhs0xZ1TBB8',
        'eventbrite' =>'8252340832',
        'featured' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 50),
        'url' => $faker->url,
        'video' => '6R2DIFySho4',
        'wikipedia' => 'Hackerspace',
        'contact_name' => $faker->name,
        'contact_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'geoloc_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Geoloc::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

UserFactory:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'avatar' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480),
        //'telephone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'role' => rand(1, 2),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

DatabaseSeeder:

```
    factory(App\User::class, 30)->create();
    factory(App\Address::class, 30)->create();
```

User relations:

```
public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entity', 'entity_user', 'user_id', 'entity_id');
}
```

Entity relations:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'entity_id');
}
public function _geoloc()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Geoloc', 'geoloc_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: How is the `users` table related to the `entities` table?

Comment: @Camilo it is related using junction table entity_user

Comment: How is the `User` model related to the `Entity` model? Show the relationship definition.

Comment: public function entities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entity', 'entity_user', 'user_id', 'entity_id');
    }

Comment: Add it to the question, it might help others too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can achieve this in your seeder like:

```php
factory(App\User::class, 30)->create()->each(function($user) {

    $entity = factory(App\Entity::class)->make();

    $address = factory(App\Address::class)->create([
        'entity_id' => $entity
    ]);

    $user->entities()->save($entity);
});
```

If you are going to create multiple entities for each user, you will need to use `saveMany()` instead of `save()`.

Comment: same  question as below:      
 
Do I need to modify the factory itself then as well? because for example address is creating a new entity and adding it's entity_id to it

Comment: You could use the same entity from the `Address` factory but you would need to query for it. I think it's more simple like this.

Comment: okay 1 quick question, it works btw. what does  $user->entities()->save($entity) working? I know it gets entity_id from $entity but how does entity_user also have correct user_id?

Comment: That would be a separate question, it's not a short answer. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this on the seeder.

For example:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Currency::class, 100)->create()->each(function ($currency) {
        $currency->variations()->saveMany(factory(App\Variation::class, 50)->make());
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to modify the factory itself then as well? because for example address is creating a new entity and adding it's entity_id to it

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem you have with your setup?